# Insertar datos en la dB mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, web

Estoy intentando guardar los datos de un usuario cuando inician sesión con discordjs pero a la hora de guardar, no lo hace y no sé qué es lo que ocurre, además he intentado de varias formas y nada.

A continuación muestro el code:

```js
router.get("/", auth, async function(req, res) {
  
  const data = req.user;
  
  conn.query(`SELECT * FROM usuariosd WHERE id_user = '${data.id}'`, function (error, results, fields) {
  // error será un error si se produjo durante la consulta
      if (error) throw error;

  // los resultados contendrán los resultados de la consulta
      if(!results) {
        
        conn.query('INSERT INTO usuariosd (username, id_user, discriminator, avatar) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)', [data.username, data.id, data.discriminator, data.avatar], function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            // Neat!
          });
          console.log("Nuevo Usuario");
        
      } else {
        
        console.log("Usuario ya Registrado")
        
      }

  // los campos contendrán información sobre los campos de resultados devueltos (si los hay)
  res.render("perfil/index.ejs", {
      login: req.isAuthenticated() ? "si": "no",
      status: req.isAuthenticated() ? "PERFIL": "LOGIN",
      loginp: (req.isAuthenticated() ? true: false),
      userBD: fields,
      user: req.user
    });
  
  
});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Error solucionado

```js
router.get("/", auth, async function (req, res) {

  const data = req.user;

  conn.query(`SELECT * FROM usuariosd WHERE id_user = '${data.id}'`, function (error, results, fields) {
    // error será un error si se produjo durante la consulta
    if (error) throw error;

    // los resultados contendrán los resultados de la consulta
    if (results.length === 0) {
      console.log("agregando usuario")
      conn.query('INSERT INTO usuariosd (username, id_user, discriminator, avatar) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)', [data.username, data.id, data.discriminator, data.avatar], function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        // Neat!
      });
      console.log("Nuevo Usuario");
    } else {
      console.log("Usuario ya Registrado")
    }

    // los campos contendrán información sobre los campos de resultados devueltos (si los hay)
    res.render("perfil/index.ejs", {
      login: req.isAuthenticated() ? "si" : "no",
      status: req.isAuthenticated() ? "PERFIL" : "LOGIN",
      loginp: (req.isAuthenticated() ? true : false),
      userBD: fields,
      user: req.user
    });
  });
})
```